# How to perform Xpath looping and skip one element

Tags: java, xml, selenium, for-loop, xpath

How to perform X path looping?

```
for  (int i=1;i<3;i++)
    String xPath = "//*[@id='rso']//h3/a["+i+"]"
    all_elements_text.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText());                  
return all_elements_text.toArray() ; }
```

i want to skip `a[2]`

Comment: if (i != 2) { do whatever you want }

Comment: but what do you want to achieve in general? maybe there is a other/better solution

Comment: actually i want to skip By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a["2"] because this is giving me error of unable to locate.

Comment: where i can use ? can you write whole code

Comment: Ankur did... I'll just point you to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165328/4273199) ^^

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just use `//*[@id='rso']//h3/a` without the index? If the `A` tag doesn't exist, it won't be returned. I feel like there's probably a better way to handle this. Please post a link to the page and explain what you are trying to accomplish. Right now people are just guessing because your actual scenario isn't understood.

Comment: @JeffC First of all the tag is `<a>` **not** `<A>`. Had you had been gone through my Answer before downvoting my Answer you would have understood it clear. Moreover you need to stop asking for **link to the page** on each and every question. That's pretty much unnecessary at-least in this case.

Comment: @DebanjanB Actually HTML, [according to the spec](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity), is case insensitive so it can be either but I capitalize them generally to make them stand out from regular text, which is especially important since a is also a word in the English language. I did go through your answer. A couple times in fact and I downvoted it because, like many of your answers, you gave bad information. I explained this in my detailed comment.

Comment: I will continue to ask for a link any time I think it's needed. You can feel free to answer without one as you wish.

Comment: @JeffC Now you are mis-guiding the entire Community. You downvoted due to lack of proper knowledge and understanding which is counter productive to our Community. Incase of Bad Information, it would have been noticed by moderators and OP and may have been deleted all together. So, read the documentations first to understand how an Answer is constructed.

Comment: @JeffC Asking for a link on each and every question doesn't make any sense. Rather you should try to concentrate on the information provided in the Question to Answer OP's question. It is not mandatory for you to attempt to Answer all the Question.

Comment: What knowledge am I missing? I linked the W3C spec for HTML... how is it wrong?

Comment: @DebanjanB nor is it mandatory for you to comment on my requests and other comments... yet you do. Feel free to ignore my request if you think it's not needed. I think a link might be helpful so I asked for it.

Comment: You asked about `What am I missing?` The answer is [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) link which is you provided is maintained by **developer.mozilla.org** and the [`getText`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) is the **JavaDoc** released and maintained by **Selenium Group**. So none are `W3C`. As per your comments, **W3C spec for HTML** and **W3C spec for WebDriver** is completely a different. For that you need to understand the current implementation of **WebDriver** first.

Comment: No. The W3C spec is how it's supposed to be (and sometimes is). The MDN docs is how Firefox implemented that function. The Selenium docs is how they implemented the function. For example, Jim Evans (the guy that mostly wrote the Selenium IE driver) has stated that the current IE driver does not match the current W3C spec because it was updated but the driver has not been updated to match. So in this case you would go to the driver documentation to see how it's currently implemented instead of the W3C spec for how it's *supposed* to be implemented.

Comment: Good to see you on track now when you say `The W3C spec is how it's supposed to be` **but not** `and sometimes is`, rather **_it should be_** . You don't have to introduce @JimEvans we all know him pretty well. The fact is though `IE driver does not match the current W3C spec` is correct. It is to be noted that **WebDriver** is now a **W3C** recommendation and all the `WebDriver` variants have to be compliant. Hence you should start following/tracking the **W3C Specs** instead of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
for  (int i=1;i<3;i++){
    if(i!=2){
        all_elements_text.add(driver.find Element(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a["+i+"]")).getText());  

    return all_elements_text.toArray() ; 
    }
```

Comment: An answer should not start with "try", try symbolizes that you had to guess where the problem could be. This means either OP was to unspecific about his problem, or you did not understand it well. An answer should be a solution and not a possibility

Comment: @Mischa Not always. You could understand the problem and have a solution but because you don't have access to the page/site, you can't test it to be sure so you state... try.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to achieve the same what you have required

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllValues()
{
    ArrayList<String> all_elements_text = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(i!=2)
        {
            all_elements_text.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a["+i+"]")).getText()); 
        }
    }
    return all_elements_text;
}
```

And Call this method from your Test where it requires to get All text and print all values e.g.

```
@Test
public void yourTestCase()
{   
     for(String s :getAllValues())
     {
         System.out.println(s);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of facts about the solution :

- Your `xpath` being indexed becomes **brittle**.
- You are never sure when `Google Analytics` changes the indexes of the search result.
- So the best practice would be to avoid and drop the keywords from the search result e.g. **`Documentation`** etc.

So keeping those in mind, lets assume we would :

- Open the `URL` **`https://www.google.com/`**
- Search for the text **`selenium webdriver`**
- From the entire search result we want to drop the results which contains the word **`Documentation`**
- Here is the sample code to search for the text **`selenium webdriver`** and drop the results containing the word **`Documentation`** :

  ```
  List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='srg']/div[@class='g']//h3/a"));
  List <String> my_text = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<my_list.size(); i++)
      if(!my_list.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Documentation"))
          my_text.add(my_list.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

Comment: Adding an index doesn't make the XPath brittle any more than assuming that the first element in a list is always the right one by using `.findElement()`, etc. Also, you keep using innerHTML when you should be using `.getText()`. They are not interchangeable. If you are going to filter out some text, it would be more efficient to do so in the locator so you don't have to loop results, e.g. `//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='srg']/div[@class='g']//h3/a[not(contains(.,"Documentation"))]`

Comment: @JeffC My sincere suggestion to you please go through the documentation of **innerHTML** and let me know if you have any query. You need to understand the difference between _getAttribute()_ and _getText()_. the **algorithm** and the **implementation** or else you will keep downvoting good answers which is counter reproductive for `StackOverflow Community`. Secondly, you need to understand how to optimize `xpath` for better performance. Third, there can be multiple ways to solve a question and my approach solves the query. You must verify yourself and retract your downvote for a better vibe.

Comment: Let me put a link to the [innerHTML documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) here so you can read it for yourself. Because if you had read it for yourself carefully, you would understand how it works. innerHTML returns `the serialized HTML code describing all of the element's descendants.` So it returns the HTML, not just the text.

Comment: `.getText()` *only* returns the text. [Here's a link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) to the Java docs for that too so you can read it and understand the difference. It returns `the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace.` So it returns only the contained text, never the HTML.

Comment: I didn't mention the performance of the XPath, you said that the XPath becomes brittle with an index but it does not and I explained why it doesn't but you never justified why it does.

Comment: On SO we aren't looking for just answers, we're looking for *good* answers and this answer has bad/incorrect information and the code is inefficient.

Comment: @JeffC Simply reading the documents won't help you either, you need to practice to understand the implementation.The doc [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) says `returns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML`, so when we are working with the last child/descendant it will always return the `text` including the leading or trailing whitespace, multiline cases which as per the docs of  [getText()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) won't.

Comment: @JeffC You have to take the pain for once to read the docs to understand more why `XPath becomes brittle with indexing`. If you have a Question raise it on StackOverflow. Volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @JeffC First, looking for just answers is helpful but downvoting good Answer due to your personal lack of understanding is counter productive for StackOverflow community. Second, if `answer has bad/incorrect information`, it would be under the ambit of Moderators and OP. You don't have to jump the gun without adequate knowledge. Third, if you feel `code is inefficient` I fail to understand why don't you get your hands-on to Answer? Your Answers not getting Acceptance/Upvotes can't be a good reason for you to downvote other volunteer's Answers.

Comment: Your comment on innerHTML vs getText and printing whitespace has no bearing on this Q. OP didn't ask for whitespace. You are also assuming that the tag that he is printing is the last child and has no descendants, which you have no info to support based on the current Q. Using innerHTML in this and probably most cases to just get the text is going to cause more problems than it solves and is unnecessary and misleading when `.getText()` will get what OP needs **and it's what he used.**

Comment: XPath does not become brittle with indexing. That's a blanket, general statement that is false and you can't prove it. In some cases it might be so but not in all so again that's misinformation. Link the docs that state that indexing causes brittleness.

Comment: If an answer has bad/incorrect info it is absolutely my job and every other SO users' job to downvote. Moderators don't come clean up all bad info... you don't understand how the site works. The downvote button that everyone has a tooltip that states, "This answer is not useful." That's why I clicked it. OP may or may not have the knowledge to downvote an answer... that's up to them to decide.

Comment: I plan to answer but I'm waiting for OP to offer a link to the page so I can see if there's a better way. If they don't provide one, I will probably post an answer.

Comment: If you look up the English Dictionary `brittle` means `Having little elasticity; hence easily cracked, fractured or snapped` which may occur when you write xpath as `//*[@id='rso']//h3/a["2"]` in the process of trying to avoid an element. The `JavaScript`/`AjaxCalls` may pull the `WebElements` randomly so your current `element no 2` may not be a `element no 2` at the next search. Hence the solution is in my Answer where I discard the `WebElement` whenever `innerHTML` contains a text. You can try it out yourself and let me know if you face any difficulty/confusion in it. I will be glad to help.